# A Sql function with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a basic function for adding logs on admin pages. (Please ignore the values).

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO logs(query,userid,time,page) VALUES('$query',$userid,NOW(),'$pagename')");
```

I'm just attempting to have it in a function like this

```
function myfunctionforlogs(){
 $sql = "INSERT INTO logs(query,userid,time,page)  VALUES('$query',$userid,NOW(),'$pagename')");
 }
```

In other pages, I'm hoping to call it as

```
myfunctionforlogs();
```

What should I do? And thanks!

Sorry all for the misunderstanding. I have about 10 admin pages and I have a table to record logs. The standard query is what I have posted above. Now, I don't want have that code in every single page, so I have a file named "func.php". I'm hoping I can have that query in a function, so I can just call the function when I want to in other files.

Comment: Not sure what your question is about. What doesn't work? What are you stuck with?

Comment: why create a new function if your code is not repeated?

Comment: Simply execute that SQL statement within a function.  Perhaps you're having trouble with the scope of your connection?  You can use `global` for that.  Also, I recommend using prepared queries with PDO to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: I have updated my question. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is really hard to understand, but maybe you want this?

```
function myfunctionforlogs($query, $userid, $pagename){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO logs(query,userid,time,page)  VALUES('$query',$userid,NOW(),'$pagename')");
    execute_sql($sql); //<-- another function, that actually runs the sql against the DB
}
```

now you can call your function anywhere you want to log the script:

```
myfunctionforlogs('select * from test', 'jimmy', 'index.php');
```

Btw. [CamelCase](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/CamelCase) is a much more readable format for function-names and identifiers in general.

Comment: That is like it, I have updated my question though, thank you for replying.